# Replace Certain Line Breaks with Equivalent of Pressing delete key on Keyboard NotePad++ Regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

Im using Notepad++ Find and replace and I have regex that looks for `[^|]\r` which will find the end of the line that starts with 8778.

```
8778|44523|0||TENNESSEE|ADMINISTRATION||ROLL 169 BATCH 8|1947-09-22|0|OnBase 
See Also 15990TT|
```

I want to basically merge that line with the one below it, so it becomes this:

```
8778|44523|0||TENNESSEE|ADMINISTRATION||ROLL 169 BATCH 8|1947-09-22|0|OnBase See Also 15990TT|
```

Ive tried the replace being a blank space, but its grabbing the last character on that line (an e in this case) and replacing that with a space, so its making it

```
8778|44523|0||TENNESSEE|ADMINISTRATION||ROLL 169 BATCH 8|1947-09-22|0|OnBas  
See Also 15990TT|
```

Is there any way to make it essentially merge the two lines?

Comment: Use `(?<!\|)\r`

Comment: I just tried this, and that makes it so that it appends onto the end of the line found, but doesnt actually remove a line break to essentially merge with the line below it

Comment: Using  ([^|])\R it ends up giving me every line, when I only want to find the ones that do not end in | . Then even the replace part I see characters CRLF at the end of each line, and this removes the LF part, but thats it and the lines arent merged

Comment: @user9758771 Yes, that is what I suspected. You need to also negate `\r`, `([^|\r])\R`. I updated my answer. (Mods removed  my comment and I did not receive notification after your comment. :()

Comment: This actually worked perfectly. Using Find as ([^|\r])\R and replace --> $1 found what I wanted and merged the lines. Thank you!

Comment: You was right if your last r letter was capital?  [^|]\R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\r` only matches a carriage return symbol, to match a line break, you need `\R` that matches any line break sequence.

To keep a part of a pattern after replacement, capture that part with parentheses, and then use a backreference to that group.

So you may use

```
([^|\r])\R
```

Replace with `$1`. Or with `$1`  if you need to append a space.

**Details**

- `([^|\r])` - Capturing group 1 (`$1` is the backreference that refers to the group value from the replacement pattern): any char other than `|` and CR
- `\R` - any line break char sequence, LF, CR or CRLF.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/369Dim/2) and the Notepad++ demo with settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you're using `[^|]` to match anything that's not a pipe character before the carriage return, which, on replacement, will remove that character (hence why you're losing an `e`).

If it's imperative that you match only carriage returns that follow non-pipe characters, capture the preceding character `([^|])\r$` and then put it back in the replacement using `$1`.

You're also missing a `\n` in your regex, which is why the replacement isn't concatenating the two lines. So your search should be `([^|])\r\n$` and your replace should be `$1`.

Comment: On Unix files `\r` is not present so it is better to use `\r?\n` to make it work there as well

Comment: For some reason ([^|])\r\n$ doesnt work for me, it seems to give me a seemingly random subset of what should be found, and the replace is acting strangly too and doesnt merge/replace. I appreciate the response though.

Answer (score -1):

Find

```
(\r\n)+
```

For "Replace" - don't put anything in (not even a space)

[image]

Comment: Why do you suggest removing all CRLF endings irrespective of the context? This goes against the OP logic to only remove a line break char sequence if it is not preceded with a pipe char.